# Content page cannot find ContentPlaceHolder 'ContentPlaceHolder1'

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I keep get an error when I load a ContentPage inside a fancybox:

```
Cannot find ContentPlaceHolder 'ContentPlaceHolder1' in the master page '/MasterPage/Modal.Master', verify content control's ContentPlaceHolderID attribute in the content page.
```

---

I have this in the MasterPage (some code omitted for simplification):

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Modal.master.cs"
Inherits="TransportadoraEDI.App.Modal" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

        <div id="main-content">

            <div style="width: 800px; height: 600px">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphConteudo" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>

            <!-- jQuery -->
            <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="../js/init.js"></script>

            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphBlocoJs" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

And this code in a ContentPage (some code omitted for simplification):

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage/Modal.Master" 
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FormCadNotFis.aspx.cs" Inherits="TransportadoraEDI.App.Conemb.FormCadNotFis" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphConteudo" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphBlocoJs" runat="server">    
</asp:Content>
```

---

How it's possible to the ContentPage look for a ContentPlaceHolder that doesn't even exists?

**EDIT**

My open fancybox function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function AbrirModal(url) {
        $.fancybox.open({
            fitToView: false,
            autoSize: false,
            href: url,
            //width: _width,
            //height: _height,
            type: 'iframe',
            transitionOut: 'none',
            centerOnScroll: true,
            hideOnOverlayClick: false,
            padding: 0,
            afterClose: function () {
                parent.location.reload(true);
            }
        });
    }; });
```

Comment: Where's the fancybox part of the code?

Comment: It's inside the init.js script. Something I forgot to mention: all the others ContentPages that use this same MasterPage are opening normally.

Comment: Please include this bit of code in your question.

Comment: I can't see anything in your code that would throw this error. Have you tried to debug it step-by-step?

Comment: Yep, I tried. Checked twice for missing closing tags, javascript errors, everything. I appreciate your effort trying to help me. Next I'll try to create a new ContentPage and reuse the same code, applying it bit by bit to see where the error is. See if it changes something. Thank you @MelanciaUK.

Answer (score 0):

There is no **ContentPlaceHolder** named '**MainContent**' in your master page,

A content place holder should be in your Master page like this:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

And child pages like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```